# I need to retrieve only the records by the logged in user

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to retrieve commission amounts for each user by the month. I keep getting back totals for all users instead of just the logged in user. The "Member" field name is the user ID. I have researched by brains out!
Now I'm just getting errors. Thanks!

DB:

[image]

```
$months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    $monthlySums = array_fill_keys($months, 0);

    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select("FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) AS Sum")
        ->from("#__rsform_submission_values")
        ->where ([
            "FormId = 46", 
            "FieldName IN (" . implode(',', $db->q($months)) . ")"
        ]) AND  ("FieldValue =.'".$_SESSION['Member'] )
        ->group("FieldName");

    //JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage($query->dump(), 'info');  // never show dump() to public

    try {
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $objects = $db->loadObjectList();
        foreach ($objects as $object) {
            $monthlySums[$object->FieldName] += $object->Sum;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        JFactory::getApplication()->enqueueMessage("Query Syntax Error: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error');  // never show getMessage() to public
    }

    foreach ($monthlySums as $month => $sum) {
        echo "<div>{$month}: {$sum}</div>";
    }
```

SQL query:

```
SELECT FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) FROM jos_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName="Jan" GROUP BY FieldName
```

Results:
Jan  510

In PHP:

```
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) FROM jos_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName=\"Jan\"     GROUP BY FieldName";

$db -> setQuery($query);

$results = $db -> loadObjectList();

foreach($results as $value){
    foreach($value as $key => $data){
        echo $key.': '.$data."<br />";
    }


echo "<br />";
}
?>
```

Results:

FieldName: Jan
SUM(FieldValue): 510

Comment: Have you checked if `$_SESSION['Member']` is getting value?

Comment: Also share  a simple MySQL query that you have converted to  `$query` here

Comment: SQL Query: 

SELECT FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) FROM jos_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName="Jan" GROUP BY FieldName

Results:
Jan  510


In Php:

$db = JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT FieldName, SUM(FieldValue) FROM jos_rsform_submission_values WHERE FieldName=\"Jan\"     GROUP BY FieldName";

$db -> setQuery($query);

$results = $db -> loadObjectList();

foreach($results as $value){
 foreach($value as $key => $data){
  echo $key.': '.$data."<br />";
 }
 echo "<br />";
}
?>

Results:

FieldName: Jan
SUM(FieldValue): 510

Comment: Because the user id is not in the same table I created a new field in my form to capture the user id and enter it in the table. It is called "Member".  It worked. Now I have the user ID in the same table. I have been trying to figure out how to query it from Phpmy admin but because I am not the logged in user it doesnt make sense to me. That's how I got stuck.

Comment: You should add code in question only... Not in comments..

Comment: You mean put the code in the Answer your Question ? Sorry! I'm so new to this!

Comment: I mean to say just edit your question and then add the code comments that you have added above.... It's hard to read the code in comments.

Comment: I think I got it all in there! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Define Session Variables From Login Page

(Login Page)

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
$_SESSION["member"] = $member;
```

Create a Member Page

```
     // Initialize the session
session_start();

// Check if the user is logged in, if not then redirect him to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: /index.php");

    exit;
}

    $requested_user = $member;

    try {

        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE member = ?");

        $stmt->execute(array($requested_user));

        $mydata = $stmt->fetch();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        //error with mysql
        die();

    }



$submissionvalueID = "{$mydata[0]}";
$formID = "{$mydata[1]}";
$submissionID = "{$mydata[2]}";
$member = "{$mydata[(member column number)]}";

echo $submissionvalueID;
```

Then You can retrieve all fields from that selected Member. You'll need to add the rest of the rows but then you can just echo the value.